# What is a clean way to replace the column values in a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, csv, replace

I have a CSV file with one column named " Battery Life ". The data can either be a number or a string attached to it. "hr" or "hrs" are those strings ( means hours of battery time ). A few samples are is 3hr, 3 hr, 3 hrs, 3hrs, etc. There are a case where the data is not available and the column value is "Not Available"

Here is the sample of the data I'm trying to manipulate. See the last column named Battery_life. dropbox.com/s/z75wleoy3153c8o/headphonesV1-csv.csv?dl=0

I'm trying to strip off the hr and hrs part from the CSV column.

This is what I did so far and it works but not a good solution and I'm not proud of it even though I started coding a couple of months back only.

```
data = open("headphonesV1 copy.csv", "r")

# join() method combines all contents of
# csvfile.csv and formed as a string
data = ''.join([i for i in data])

# search and replace the contents
data = data.replace("hrs", "")
data = data.replace("hr", "")


# output.csv is the output file opened in write mode
x = open("headphonesV1 copy.csv", "w")

# all the replaced text is written in the output.csv file
x.writelines(data)
x.close()
```

Another method I tried is to define a function like the following and do a string replacement from the column.

```
def clean_battery_string(input_string):

    if "hrs" in input_string:

        clean_string = input_string.replace("hrs", '')
        print(clean_string)
    elif "hr" in input_string:
        clean_string = input_string.replace("hr", '')
        print(clean_string)
    else:
        clean_string = input_string
        print(clean_string)

    return clean_string
```

but I'm not sure how to apply this function. Can someone help

Answer (score 0):

Your second variant will not work, because if you have in string hrs and hr, only hrs will be replaced.

The first variant not bad, but I want to optimize your code.

```
data = open("headphonesV1 copy.csv", "r")

# join() method combines all contents of
# csvfile.csv and formed as a string
data = data.read()

# search and replace the contents
data = data.replace("hrs", "")
data = data.replace("hr", "")


# output.csv is the output file opened in write mode
x = open("headphonesV1 copy.csv", "w")

# all the replaced text is written in the output.csv file
x.write(data)
x.close()
```

First, I use `data.read()` (returns one `str` with `\n` symbols) instead of `''.join([i for i in data])` if you want to output file have multilines, like input.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Thank you. But say if hr or hrs is in any other columns, will this code replace them as well? That was the problem with my code.

Comment: @TonyPaul CSV is a text file with data, separated by a comma. This code will replace all `hrs` and `hr` in the document. Maybe I didn't understand your example of the file? Can you copy/paste your file on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com)?

Comment: I haven't used paste bin yet. Here is a sample of the file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/z75wleoy3153c8o/headphonesV1-csv.csv?dl=0 . See the last column name battery life.

Comment: @TonyPaul, yes, it will work with your table

Comment: Is there a neat way of doing the same by reading the CSV, iterate over each value, and replacing the value in the CSV file? With or without using the  clean_battery_string() function I wrote above?